# Summarize word count in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I'd like to generate a frequency count summary of frequencies of word counts in a dplyr pipe. It has to be in a dplyr pipe because I am actually querying from bigrquery and it acts as a dplyr pipe.

Suppose I have data like this:

```
tf1 <- tbl_df(data.frame(row= c(1:5), body=c("tt t ttt j ss oe", "kpw eero", "pow eir sap r", "s", "oe")))
```

I'd like to have a summary of the word counts (something like this):

```
   n_words freq
1   0    0
2   1    2
3   2    1
4   3    0
5   4    1
6   5    0
7   6    1
```

**But I need to do this in a dplyr pipe (something like below that does not work)**

```
###NOT WORK
tf1 %>%
wordcount(body,sep=" ", count.function=sum)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another idea that also uses `complete` to get all values,

```
library(tidyverse)

tf1 %>% 
   mutate(n_words = stringr::str_count(body, ' ') + 1) %>% 
   count(n_words) %>% 
   complete(n_words = 0:max(n_words))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 2
>   n_words     n
>     <dbl> <int>
> 1      0.    NA
> 2      1.     2
> 3      2.     1
> 4      3.    NA
> 5      4.     1
> 6      5.    NA
> 7      6.     1
> ```

Comment: alternative word count method: `stringi::stri_count_words(body)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tf1 %>% mutate(wordcount = str_split(body, " ") %>% lengths()) %>% count(wordcount)
## # A tibble: 4 x 2
##   wordcount     n
##       <int> <int>
## 1         1     2
## 2         2     1
## 3         4     1
## 4         6     1
```

`str_split(tf1$body, " ")` returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "tt"  "t"   "ttt" "j"   "ss"  "oe" 

[[2]]
[1] "kpw"  "eero"

[[3]]
[1] "pow" "eir" "sap" "r"  

[[4]]
[1] "s"

[[5]]
[1] "oe"
```

`lengths` calculate the length of each list element, therefore

```
str_split(tf1$body, " ") %>% lengths()
## [1] 6 2 4 1 1
```

This is added as column `wordcount` by using `mutate`

`count` returns how many times a value is found in the column `wordcount` and stores that as column `n`